# Could not find inline variable integration in delphi seattle nor Code Analysis

Tags: delphi, code-analysis, delphi-10-seattle

In Delphi XE8 I made use of the Castalia [Inline Variable Integration](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/How_to_Use_Inline_Variable_Declaration_(Castalia)) and [Code Analysis](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Castalia_Overview#Castalia_Menu) facilities.

I cannot find this functionality in Delphi 10 Seattle. Does it still exist? If so, where can I find it? If it does not exist, are there alternatives that I can use?

Comment: Please give some more background? Is this related to Castalia? Where we're you expecting to find them?

Comment: On Delphi XE8, there was a Castalia Menu, and now and as far as I know, castalia is integrated to the Ide, and there is no castalia menu, because of that, I dont speak about castalia.
I don't expect any thing, only a help.

Comment: You'd get better help if the question had all this detail. Everything you said in that comment should be in the question. And as to what you expect, well you said that in the comment. What you expect is to be able to find the functionality that was previously available through the xxx action on the Castalia menu in previous version.

Comment: Yes, this is the first time I ask a question on StackOverflow, usualy I find the answer because someone else has get help by asking before, so sorry if don't help you to help

Comment: I've modify the details, hope that it's more precise

Comment: I've made an edit to the question to ask it in the way that I hope is clearer.  I've also added an answer that I suspect won't be to your liking. Not that I think that my answer is wrong, rather than I think you may not like the news that I bring you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Castalia creator here. I'm glad you're getting good use from it! Here's where you can find that functionality in RAD Studio 10 Seattle:

Inline Variable Declaration: Press Ctrl+J, then type "var" and hit .

Code metrics: From the "Project" menu, choose "QA Metrics."

Comment: Hi Jacob
It's an honnor for me to recieve a help from you.
I largely prefer your philosophy that group variables that have a same type rather than having one line per variable, and with your facility, only pressing spacebar declare and the variabe is ready to recive value.
About QA Metrics, I'll never use it, too complicated, there is no comparision between the beautiful array with comprehensive colours than the one given, and unindertanding one given with Seattle.
Hop that Embarcadero return to more simplicity that you provide for us.

Comment: Hmm..not all of Castalia's refactorings existed in older versions of Delphi, notably the "Eliminate 'with'" option. Hopefully Embarcadero will reintroduce this potentially useful feature.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it, Embarcadero have removed the refactoring part of Castalia because it simply duplicates the existing refactoring of the product. They don't want to offer the confusion is two different ways to achieve the same goals. The primary reason for acquiring Castalia is to integrate the code structure highlighting.

The closest refactoring to Castalia's *Inline Variable Integration* is [Declare Variable](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declare_Variable). Alternatively you can use a live template.

Similarly, for Castalia Code Analysis, this simply provides functionality parallel to the existing [QA Audits and Metrics](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Source_Code_Audits_and_Metrics) feature. You are expected to use that functionality now.

Comment: There are also code editor templates that facilitate inline declaration of variables. They should be easy to find.